# Can we use GIT for Oracle Service Bus projects and BPEL projects?

Tags: soa, bpel, osb

We are planning to introduce GIT for OSB and BPEL project is it a correct option.. Not sure how it will compare the jars??

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. We are using git for OSB projects and it works really great.

After creating workspace, you should add it to your git repository. Thanks to that you will be able to track all files individually. You can of course store in that repository your jars, but because of comapring problems I would treat is as a backup.

I also believe that the same approach (adding workspace to git repo) can be used for BPEL projects, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can.

Both **OSB and BPEL projects are simply .xml files**. If you open the project, you will see .xml, .wsdl, .xsd, etc. All these files can be tracked by a version controll system (GIT, mercurial, SVN).

Answer (score 0):

Source control is for source code and not for jars. In the case of OSB, the source code would be mostly XML files (proxies, pipelines, bix) or XQuery & XSL. 
Git would work perfectly well - you would need to define and follow some practices around versioning, branching, tagging etc.

Exactly the same principles would work for SOA composites (that include BPEL). 
I have an example right here: https://github.com/jvsingh/SOATestingWithCitrus

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you may use GIT for both OSB and BPEL projects. We are also using GIT in our current project, but as far as comparing the jars is concerned you cannot compare the jars in GIT.
So what we are checking in the source code as well to track and compare the previous change.